# Trying to reduce the speed overhead of an almost-but-not-quite-int number class

Tags: c++, optimization, numbers, operator-overloading

I have implemented a C++ class which behaves very similarly to the standard `int` type. The difference is that it has an additional concept of "epsilon" which represents some tiny value that is much less than 1, but greater than 0. One way to think of it is as a very wide fixed point number with 32 MSBs (the integer parts), 32 LSBs (the epsilon parts) and a huge sea of zeros in between. (Note: A big difference between this class and normal fixed point numbers is that there are two signs, not one: "value" and "epsilon" can be negative independently of each other, whereas for fixed point, there is one sign for the entire number.)

The following class works, but introduces a ~2x speed penalty in the overall program. (The program includes code that has nothing to do with this class, so the actual speed penalty of this class is probably much greater than 2x.) I can't paste the code that is using this class, but I can say the following:

`+, -, +=, <, >` and `>=` are the only heavily used operators. Use of `setEpsilon()` and `getInt()` is extremely rare. `*` is also rare, and does not even need to consider the epsilon values at all.

Here is the class:

```
#include <limits>

struct int32Uepsilon {
typedef int32Uepsilon Self;

int32Uepsilon () { _value = 0;
                   _eps   = 0; }
int32Uepsilon (const int &i) { _value = i;
                               _eps   = 0; }
void setEpsilon() { _eps = 1; }
Self operator+(const Self &rhs) const { Self result = *this;
                                      result._value += rhs._value;
                                      result._eps   += rhs._eps;
                                      return result; }
Self operator-(const Self &rhs) const { Self result = *this;
                                      result._value -= rhs._value;
                                      result._eps   -= rhs._eps;
                                      return result; }
Self operator-(               ) const { Self result = *this;
                                      result._value = -result._value;
                                      result._eps   = -result._eps;
                                      return result; }
Self operator*(const Self &rhs) const { return this->getInt() * rhs.getInt(); } // XXX: discards epsilon

bool operator<(const Self &rhs) const { return (_value < rhs._value) ||
                                             (_value == rhs._value && _eps < rhs._eps); }
bool operator>(const Self &rhs) const { return (_value > rhs._value) ||
                                             (_value == rhs._value && _eps > rhs._eps); }
bool operator>=(const Self &rhs) const { return (_value >= rhs._value) ||
                                             (_value == rhs._value && _eps >= rhs._eps); }

Self &operator+=(const Self &rhs) { this->_value += rhs._value;
                                  this->_eps   += rhs._eps;
                                  return *this; }
Self &operator-=(const Self &rhs) { this->_value -= rhs._value;
                                  this->_eps   -= rhs._eps;
                                  return *this; }
int getInt() const { return(_value); }

private:
  int _value;
  int _eps;
};

namespace std {
template<>
struct numeric_limits<int32Uepsilon> {
  static const bool is_signed  = true;
  static int max() { return 2147483647; }
}
};
```

The code above works, but it is quite slow. Does anyone have any ideas on how to improve performance? There are a few hints/details I can give that might be helpful:

- 32 bits are definitely insufficient to hold both _value and _eps. In practice, up to 24 ~ 28 bits of
  _value are used and up to 20 bits of _eps are used.
- I could not measure a significant performance difference between using `int32_t` and `int64_t`,
  so memory overhead itself is probably not the problem here.
- Saturating addition/subtraction on _eps would be cool, but isn't really necessary.
- Note that the signs of _value and _eps are not necessarily the same! This broke my first attempt
  at speeding this class up.
- Inline assembly is no problem, so long as it works with GCC on a Core i7 system running Linux!

Comment: You're doing 2 integer operations in each overload, and you're wondering why you get a 2x performance penalty vs. standard integers?!  More seriously, you are fundamentally doing twice as much work, so whatever optimisations you come up with (SSE vectorisation, etc.), this will always perform twice as slow (roughly speaking) compared to the same optimisations made to straightforward integer maths.

Comment: @Oli : The 2x performance overhead is of the entire application, which includes a fair amount of code that has nothing to do with this class. If I had to guess, I would say that the performance hit of dealing with these things instead of ints is 5x or more. (Edit: I'm sorry, the question suggests the opposite. I've fixed it.)

Comment: @Nawaz : If I had to give just one, I would say +. However, < and > would be a very close second.

Comment: Profile the code so that you actually *know* where the bottlenecks are, then you can focus on optimising the specific areas that actually need it, instead of just speculatively messing with the code in the hope that it might help.

Comment: @Paul : This has been difficult, because disabling compiler optimizations leads profiles that are readable but warped, but enabling them leads to profiles that are pretty much useless. Unless you mean profile in the sense of count the frequency of the various functions in the class, which I have done. +, < and > happen billions of times, -, >=, += happen tens of millions of times, and everything else happens just a handful, in the typical case.

Comment: I agree with @Paul R.  But as a style note (and a slight possibility of a speed improvement), use member initializers in your constructors, not assignment.

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: See my partial solution. And suggest some improvements.

Comment: @Fumiyo Eda: if you use a decent profiler, e.g. Zoom from http://rotateright.com, then you should be able to compile with `gcc -O3 -g ...` and get a meaningful profile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One thing to try is the canonical practice of defining e.g. `operator+` in terms of `operator+=`:

```
Self operator+(const Self &rhs) const { return Self(*this) += rhs; }
```

This facilitates the [return-value optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization), which eliminates the copy constructor that would otherwise be needed for return-by-value.

Also, it reduces code maintenance!

Comment: Make the operator a free function: `int32Uepsilon operator+(int32Uepsilon lhs, const int32Uepsilon& rhs) { return lhs += rhs; }`. This allowes the compiler to elide the copy made with pass by value.

Comment: @Oli: `Self(*this) += rhs;` You're making a new copy of `*this`.

Comment: @Xeo: You have to make a copy somewhere, as `operator+` returns a new instance.  Also, `return lhs += rhs;` is *extremely* bad, as it alters the value of `lhs`!

Comment: @Oli: Notice that I pass lhs by value to the free standing operator+. [See this article](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/).

Comment: @Xeo: That's a good point; I hadn't noticed that!  Nevertheless, we cannot avoid a constructor call here somewhere, because we start with two instances, and end up with three.

Comment: @Oli : Wow. I made that change and it improved overall program performance by 5%! This is building code with g++ 4.3 at -O3. I'm curious though: why can't the compiler see that the copy constructor isn't necessary? I'm very surprised that this kind of change would have such an effect. Can you explain what is going on in a bit more detail?

Comment: @Fumiyo Eda: check the article @Xeo referred to, it gives some details on such optimizations

Comment: @Fumiyo: The C++ standard doesn't allow it to eliminate construction of *named* variables, i.e. lvalues.  It is allowed to optimise away temporaries, i.e. *rvalues*, though.

Comment: @Oli: but NRVO means that the newly created named value can be initialized directly in the memory location of the return value.

Answer (score 2):

2x speed penalty does not seem unreasonable since all operations are done twice.

You might use MMX/SSE2 instructions to pack value and epsilon in two registers and perform the two operations in parallel only once. Alternatively, on 64-bit architecture you can pack the two values in a single int64, as in: `[32 bits of value][12 zeros][20 bits of eps]`. Comparisons would work automatically with a single operations, addition and subtraction would need to mask out carry over from eps into padding zeros. There's no obstacle to using MMX for addition and subtraction (masking out happens automatically then) and ordinary integer comparison for comparisons.

BTW , your operator-= seems to be buggy: in `this->_eps   -= rhs._eps`, `this->eps` can become negative. Shouldn't you then adjust both eps and decrement the value? What is the overflow behavior of eps? Does it ever carry over into value?

Comment: I'm on a 64-bit machine, so I'll need to give int64 a try. As for operator-=, I think it is OK, negative eps is no problem. As for overflow, ideally eps would saturate and not carry into value, but I think it would happen so rarely (if eps was 32 bits) that it probably isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: This is very attractive, and it seems the GCC MMX intrinsics builtin_ia32_paddd and builtin_ia32_psubd will do the trick for +/-. However, I don't think ordinary integer comparison will work, due to the sign issue. For example, an instance with value 0x00000001 and eps is 0xFFFFFFFF (-1) will compare as _greater_ than an instance with value 0x00000001 and eps 0x00000001 (1). Unfortunately, I couldn't find any comparison intrinsics that looked particularly helpful.

Answer (score 1):

My (partial) solution is using **one** integer operation, instead of **two** in your solution as pointed out by **Oli Charlesworth** in the comment.

Here is how you can do: use `int64_t` to store both `_eps` and `_value`. In my example below, `_value` is represent by `bit0-to-bit31` and `_eps` is represented by `bit32-to-bit63`.

```
struct int32Uepsilon 
{

   typedef int32Uepsilon Self;

   int64_t value;

   int32Uepsilon () { value = 0 }
   int32Uepsilon (const int i) {  value = i; }
   void setEpsilon() 
   {  
      //equivent to _eps = 1
      value = ((int64_t)1 << 32) + (value & 0xFFFFFFFF); 
   }
   Self operator+(const Self &rhs) const 
   { 
     Self result = *this;
    //this adds lower 32 bits to lower 32 bits, upper 32 bits to upper 32 bits!
     result.value += rhs.value; 
     return result; 
   }
   //....
   int getValue() { return value & 0xFFFFFFFF; }
   int getEpsilon() { return value >> 32; }
};
```

If there is no overflow, then `+` can be done efficiently and reliably. This is a just a start. Try thinking if other operations can be done reliably using some bit-operations.

---

A simple demonstration of addition. Please read the comment

```
int main() 
{
    int64_t x =  ((int64_t)2 << 32) + 4;     //eps = 2,  value = 4
    int64_t y =  ((int64_t)65 << 32) +7897;  //eps = 65, value = 7897
    int64_t z =  x + y ; //in z, eps = (2+65) = 67, value = (4 + 7897) = 7901 
    cout << (x >> 32) << ", " << (x & 0xFFFFFFFF) << endl;  
    cout << (y >> 32) << ", " << (y & 0xFFFFFFFF) << endl;  
    cout << (z >> 32) << ", " << (z & 0xFFFFFFFF) << endl;  
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2, 4    
65, 7897   
67, 7901
```

as expected.

Demo at Ideone: http://www.ideone.com/GjSnJ

---

Instead of `x + y`, you can use `x | y` which is even [faster operation](http://www.ideone.com/2gIx1).

Comment: I'm not sure this will work for negative values. If value is -1 and eps is 1, if I am understanding correctly you represent this as 0x00000001FFFFFFFF. If we add two of these, we get 0x00000003FFFFFFFE, which is value -2 and eps 3? The expected result is value -2 and eps 2.

Comment: @Oli and @Fumiyo: Think, Think. Maybe, there is some solution, some  trick waiting for us. I'm also thinking :D

Comment: @Oli and @Fumiyo: Based on the sign of values, we can write some if-else. That would solve the problem, I think.

Comment: @Nawaz: `if-else` would slow things down to a crawl.  This is basically just SIMD vectorisation that you're trying to achieve here!  SSE already has instructions that do this sort of thing; it's just a question of whether the compiler is able to spot that it can use them.

Comment: @Nawaz: I agree with Oli that SIMD type operations might be useful. In fact, since I expect that wraparound will never occur for both value and eps, any kind of vector-type instruction (saturating or not) is probably going to work. It has been 10 years since I last had to delve into this kind of assembly trickery, so it is time to read some manuals - once I can find them! I have no idea what kind of operations are available these days.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the input, everyone. In the end, I used inline assembly to implement +, - and +=. Amazingly, GCC could not vectorize these tiny functions by itself, though using the `__builtin_ia32_paddd()` builtin helped somewhat. Eventually, the overall program overhead (compared to using bare `int`) was reduced from 100% to 50%. Looking at the generated assembly, the result seemed to be optimal, at least where I looked. As far as I could tell from a quick read of the Intel manuals, there is nothing to help with the comparison operations. (There are vector comparison instructions, but none of them are helpful here.)